# Apologizing informally

Tags: grammar, phrase-request, expressions, phrases

Is it appropriate to say

> 'Sorry for making this hard for you'?

Some context: We tried to set up a time to meet but we have conflicting schedules so we decided to meet later at night.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it's not that hard but just inconvenient. I think I'd say, "Sorry for the inconvenience." If you want something more original, you might want to try "Sorry we can't make it earlier. Thanks for agreeing to meet in the evening."

Comment: The trouble with "sorry for the inconvenience" is that it has become a kind of stock phrase used by corporations who really don't feel sorry at all. when my recent railway journey was delayed by several hours I was emphatically not appeased by the railway company apologising for the "inconvenience". Inconvenience! You destroyed my weekend!

Comment: @JeremyC you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you do not wish to suggest that it is the other guy's fault. If you say it is hard for them, then potentially someone else would not find it so hard - so it is their fault!

So you must therefore imply that only you are to blame. One way of saying that would be to say "I am sorry to be so difficult..."